# Как узнать из-за чего выпадает NumberFormatException, если ошибку в коде Android Monitor не показывает?

Tags: java, android

Писал код по [этому](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html) уроку, приложение должно поворачивать FrameLayout по нажатию кнопки. При нажатии той самой кнопки приложение вылетает вот ошибка:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "@2131427329"
at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:375)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:366)
at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.convertValueToInt(XmlUtils.java:122)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getInt(TypedArray.java:254)
at android.animation.AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(AnimatorInflater.java:188)
at android.animation.AnimatorInflater.loadObjectAnimator(AnimatorInflater.java:161)
at android.animation.AnimatorInflater.createAnimatorFromXml(AnimatorInflater.java:117)
at android.animation.AnimatorInflater.createAnimatorFromXml(AnimatorInflater.java:126)
at android.animation.AnimatorInflater.createAnimatorFromXml(AnimatorInflater.java:93)
at android.animation.AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(AnimatorInflater.java:72)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.loadAnimator(FragmentManager.java:738)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:953)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeFragment(FragmentManager.java:1162)
at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:639)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:441)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

В приложении всего 1 класс и там нет переменных int только в ресурсах есть 2 . В чем может быть ошибка в таком случае ?

Comment: проверьте разметку фрагмента, там где создаётся анимация. там где-то  @ в начале id элемента.

Comment: @pavel так android:id="@+id/text" тоже нельзя что ли ?

Comment: @pavel проверил несколько раз все id в норме

Comment: @pavel вы правы только @ была не в id, а в android:duration, там дальше ссылка была на ресурс который содержал 2 int значения, после смены ссылки на соответствующие числа все заработало

Comment: @pavel взята идея из гугловского примера, надо бы посмотреть почему эта конструкция работала у них

Comment: Очевидно, эта конструкция в гугловском примере работала потому, что в их проекте данные ресурсы присутствовали, а в вашем - нет.

Comment: @pavlofff есть у меня эти ресурсы, я даже в вопросе указал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NumberFormatExeption` в данном случае  говорит о том, что не удалось строку с числом из ресурсов преобразовать в целое число (строка содержит символы не пригодные для конвертации) . Смотрите, как вы указали значение, можете  [скачать исходник](https://developer.android.com/shareables/training/Animations.zip) их проекта и сравнить со своим.